# Angular animation duration ignored?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I'm learning animations with Angular but I'm stuck.

Here's my simple fade animation:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
   animations:[
     trigger('formState',[
       state('hidden',style({
         opacity: 0
       })),
       state('visible',style({
         opacity: 1
       })),
       transition('hidden => visible', animate("1s ease-in")),
       transition('visible => hidden', animate("1s ease-in"))
     ])
   ]
})
```

It seems like the duration of `1s` I've specified is being ignored, and my opacity changes instantly when I change the state.

I've written this code following [this](https://angular.io/guide/animations#duration) and adapting to my needs.

What am I doing wrong in the definition of my animation?

Let me know if other files are needed here, because I'm a total newbie at `Angular`!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted, so you might have forgotten to add the animations module in your component:

```
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';
```

And of course you have to add [`BrowserAnimationsModule`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/animations/BrowserAnimationsModule) to the imports in your main module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserAnimationsModule, BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I made a [StackBlitz using your animation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qe4r8w).

**UPDATE**

You will need to use the [Web Animations
  polyfill](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#enabling-polyfills) in several cases.

I updated [the StackBiltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rbpmsa). You may have to import the polyfill differently depending on your configuration.

I tested on Safari (MacOS) and it did not work before adding the polyfill ([initial StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qe4r8w)), and now it does.

Comment: My imports were correct. Can this be related to the fact that I was using Safari? Here at work your example (very equal to mine, apart from the hello component) works on Firefox. I'm going to look better on my Mac at home and let you know. Thank you!